# AdMob banner is working with test ad unit ID but empty with real ad unit ID

Tags: ios, admob

I have set up AdMob for my iOS app. When I use adUnitID for testing I can see test ads on my device. However, when I use real ad unit ID that is assigned to my app, the banner is empty.

The app is not in the App Store yet. I am just doing the final tests on my iPhone. I wonder if I should put my app to the App Store to be able to see the ads, or not. This is my first app, so I don't know. Is it related?

I cannot see any error in my AdMob account. I see some messages in the console but they don't seem related with this issue (modified to hide personal info):

```
2019-11-23 16:54:30.297060-0600 NameOfTheApp[0000:0000000]  - <Google>[I-AAA000000] AdMob App ID changed. Original, new: (nil), ca-app-pub-0000000000000000~0000000000
2019-11-23 16:54:30.297934-0600 NameOfTheApp[0000:0000000]  - <Google>[I-AAA000000] Analytics v.60105000 started
2019-11-23 16:54:30.321734-0600 NameOfTheApp[0000:0000000]  - <Google>[I-AAA000000] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -APMAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see goo.gl/000000)
2019-11-23 16:54:30.371010-0600 NameOfTheApp[0000:0000000]  - <Google>[I-AAA000000] Purchase is a duplicate and will not be reported. Product ID: com.acme.NameOfTheApp.NameOfTheInAppPurchaseProduct
2019-11-23 16:54:30.372211-0600 NameOfTheApp[0000:0000000] <Google> To get test ads on this device, set: GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = @[ @"000000000000000000000000000000" ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it was due to missing payment information. In the AdMob website it was stated that payment information is required to load ads. After reading that I have entered my payment information and waited for 24 hours. Now ads are loading with real ID.